# Check task assignee whether in candidate groups

Tags: activiti, camunda

ENV: camunda 7.4

Given: all user tasks have candidate groups assigned at modelling time. At runtime user tasks can be claimed using TaskService.claim().

Expect: assignee is in candidate groups. If not, throw authorization exception

Attempt: add a task listener for event name 'assignment' to every user task programmatically to perform the check using identity service

Is this good practice? If not, suggestions?
If alright, how to achieve this? Something similar to [bpmn-parse-listener](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/process-engine-plugin/bpmn-parse-listener) for TaskListener? (specifically following the example got the problem upon using ActivityImpl in method parseUserTask of AbstractBpmnParseListener to add listener: TaskListener vs. ExecutionListener)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution at [add task listener to all user tasks](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-consulting/tree/master/snippets/task-name-beautifier#adding-the-task-listener-to-all-user-tasks-of-all-processes). Although not sure if this way of checking assignment is good practice.